# How is Bavuma the first black South African cricketer to make a test century?

Tags: cricket, trivia, records

I may be missing something but it's all over the news. I don't understand because JP Duminy has scored 4 test centuries. Is there something here I'm missing ?

Answer (score 10):

JP Duminy is from the Cape Coloured ethnic grouping (see http://www.cricketwa.com/370/player/jean-paul-duminy.aspx), hence is not considered Black African.

Note: I'm not commenting on whether these ethnic groupings are appropriate or even palatable. They're what's in use in South Africa today. I'm not South African, or resident there.

Comment: No offence but what is the difference ?

Comment: None taken. You asked why JP Duminy's centuries didn't count, and I explained - he's not considered, in South African parlance, as Black African. Discussing whether this is a correct judgement, or if the categories are even valid, is not a topic for this forum.

Comment: I am neither asking if the judgement is correct nor if the categories are valid. I'm merely asking for more information about what Duminy's race is because I never heard that word before today.

Comment: The link in my answer states "The Cape Coloured ethnic group of South Africa comprises of people belonging to mixed race."

Comment: Can you tell me who are the black Africans to play for South Africa ? Which category do Ntini, Prince, Philander, Tsosobe, Piedte fall under ?

Comment: This information would be available from a Google search.

Comment: Most coloured people would take offense to being categorized as black. There culture is totally different to that which is considered black. There is more to definition of culture groups in South Africa than just skin colour.

Comment: and even among the term "black" there are cultures among them that differ as well. Xhosas,and Zulus are not the same.